# How to freeze scroll on a control during animation?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls

C#, WinForms, I made my own `UserControl` named `ListOfControls` that takes other `controls` and displays them like a vertical layout like so:

```
|-------------------|
|    Control 1      |
|-------------------|
|-------------------|
|    Control 2      |
|-------------------|
|-------------------|
|    Control 3      |
|-------------------|
```

As you imagine, list gets large so I apllied `AutoScroll` on `ListOfControls`. Now sometimes I want to swap `Control 1` and `26` at runtime, for example. Because `Control 26` is way below current visible area (user sees only first 9 controls, then he has to scroll) I have to account for the `VerticalScroll.Value` of the `ListOfControls`

And here is the catch: Swapping of controls is animated (`Control 1` moves down, `Control 26` moves up) and `AutoScroll` is enabled so during the animation the scroll tries to account for it but in the end totally messes up the Control's final location.

Is there anyway how to freeze the scroll at its current position and wait for the animation to finish?

Comment: Turn off AutoScroll and set the AutoScrollMinSize yourself.

Comment: @LarsTech That worked. You can write it as an answer if you want, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent the AutoScroll fireworks that happens when you are moving controls, it is best to control the environment yourself.  Set the AutoScroll property to false and set the AutoScrollMinSize property to the size of canvas your controls are occupying.